# Why EF Core FromSql with a stored procedure that returns result of left outer join repeats data records

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I'm developing an inventory system, I have three classes

- Producto (Product)
- Almacen (Warehouse)
- ProductoAlmacen (ProductWarehouse)

So we have productos, and almacenes and we have a relation producto-almacen that keeps the available inventory of the producto in each almacen.

```
public class Producto 
{
   [Key]
   public int ProductoId { get; set; }

   [StringLength (100)]
   public string Nombre { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [Column (TypeName = "decimal(10, 2)")]
   public decimal Costo { get; set; }

   public ICollection<ProductoAlmacen> ProductosAlmacen { get; set; }
}

public class Almacen 
{
  [Key]
  public int AlmacenId { get; set; }

  [StringLength (100)]
  public string Nombre { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public Estatus EstatusId { get; set; }

  public ICollection<ProductoAlmacen> ProductosAlmacen { get; set; }
}

public class ProductoAlmacen 
{
   public int ProductoAlmacenId { get; set; }
   public int ProductoId { get; set; }
   public Producto Producto { get; set; }

   public int AlmacenId { get; set; }
   public Almacen Almacen { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [Column (TypeName = "decimal(10, 2)")]
   public decimal CantidadDisponible { get; set; }
}
```

I need a screen that shows a product with everyone of the almacenes existence even if there is not an entry in table `ProductoAlmacen`. In order to accomplish this I create a stored procedure with a left outer join, That I execute and returns this

```
ProductoAlmacenId   ProductoId  AlmacenId   CantidadDisponible
12                      1           5           9.00
6                       1           4           4.00
4                       1           3           3.00
3                       1           2           2.00
1                       1           1           1.00
0                       1           6           0.00
0                       1           7           0.00
0                       1           8           0.00
```

My code:

```
var pas = await _context.ProductoAlmacen
        .FromSql($"EXECUTE dbo.spGetProductosAlmacenAsync @ProductoId", 
         sqlProductoId)
        .ToListAsync();
```

The stored procedure is:

```
SELECT   
    ProductoAlmacenId = ISNULL(ProductoAlmacenId, 0),
    ProductoId = @ProductoId,
    AlmacenId = A.AlmacenId,
    CantidadDisponible = ISNULL(PA.CantidadDisponible, 0),
    CantidadMinimo = ISNULL(PA.CantidadMinimo, 0),
    CantidadMaximo = ISNULL(PA.CantidadMaximo, 0),
    CantidadPuntoReorden = ISNULL(PA.CantidadPuntoReorden, 0) 
FROM 
    Almacen A
LEFT JOIN 
    ProductoAlmacen PA ON PA.AlmacenId = A.AlmacenId 
                       AND PA.ProductoId = @ProductoId  
ORDER BY 
    PA.AlmacenId DESC
```

Reviewing the result collection, the first 6 records are all correct, records 7 and 8 are the same as record number 6 (ProductoAlmacenId: 0, ProductoId: 1, AlmacenId 6, CantidadDisponible: 0.00)

I believe it's probably because of ProductoAlmacenId value is 0, is there a way a round of this?

Comment: You're **not showing** us the most important piece - the **stored procedure** !

Comment: I added the sp, Thanks Marc

Comment: Remove `ProductoAlmacenId` from the database and your model. It's not a unique key and hence it's useless and even harmful. Create a new composite primary key consisting of `ProductoId` and `AlmacenId`, which is the usual approach for junction tables.